# How to use stringr and forcats package in R more efficiently?

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr, forcats

I am confused that how to combine `stringr` package in a pipline data analysis process. The `stringr` project is a string vector (single column), the origin data (multi-column) convert into single column, the output can not be directly used in later process with `%>%` for function like `summarise` in `dplyr`, and have to re-assign to new project, the way seems not so gentle, is there any smooth way to process the data?

Here is an example code, and can the `str_replace` procedure be combind with `sum` procedure with pipeline  `%>%`

```
# prepare dara
library(tidyr, dplyr)
name <- c('D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'd', 'e', 'f' )
room <- rep(c('A','B'),c(4,3))
goal <- c(rnorm(7,mean=60,sd=10))
test <- data.frame(name,goal,room)

# replace 'G' in name to 'H'
test$name <- str_replace(test$name, 'G', 'H') 

# SUM (calculate)
test %>% group_by(name) %>% summarise(sum(goal))
```

I just want to know how to connect `stringr`  with other data processes, can it be or be not? I know there it can be solved in a factor way (`forcats`): change the string vector into factor vector and  relevel the factor, and here is another problem: how to process partly factor vetor more gently, and here is an example:

```
library(dplyr,forcats,dplyr)
name1 <- c('D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'D', 'E', 'F' )
room <- rep(c('A','B'),c(4,3))
goal <- c(rnorm(7,mean=60,sd=10))
test1 <- data.frame(name1,goal,room)

## split and recombine the test1 data, I just want to change the name level of room B ##, but just change name directly in data test1 will change the level of room A at ##the same time
test1A <- test1 %>% filter(room == 'A') 
test1B <- test1 %>% filter(room == 'B') 
test1B %>% mutate(name1 = fct_recode(name1, 'DD'='D','EE'='E','FF'='F'))
test1 <- bind_rows(test1A, test1B)
```

Can the partly recode purpose be more gentle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including `stringr` code in pipes is same as all other code. You can do -

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

test %>%
  group_by(name = str_replace(name, 'G', 'H')) %>%
  summarise(goal = sum(goal))

#  name   goal
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 d      46.9
#2 D      57.4
#3 e      61.3
#4 E      61.5
#5 f      59.8
#6 F      67.2
#7 H      50.0
```

---

Similarly, for `forcats` code -

```
test1 %>% 
  filter(room == 'B') %>%
  mutate(name1 = fct_recode(name1, 'DD'='D','EE'='E','FF'='F')) %>%
  bind_rows(test1 %>% filter(room == 'A'))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `base R`

```
aggregate(goal ~ name, transform(test, chartr('G', 'H', name)), sum)
```

-ouput

```
name     goal
1    d 55.97663
2    D 65.21457
3    e 76.83987
4    E 41.75801
5    f 49.27920
6    F 70.87190
7    G 58.63348
```

Comment: Good expression, A new syntax for me to learn!